# How should I construct C++ members that depend on each other?

Tags: c++, pointers, members

I have a class using a library for communication that's like so:

```
class Topic {
  Topic( Type T, String name );
};

class Reader {
  Reader (Topic, String name);
};

class Writer {
  Writer (Topic, String name);
};
```

I want to make a talker class like so:

```
Talker (Type T, String name);
```

And generate the member Writer and Reader with the constructor.

I'm torn between doing it with pointers:

```
class Talker {
  Topic* m_Topic;
  Reader* m_Reader;
  Writer* m_Writer;

  Talker (Type T, String name) {
    m_Topic = new Topic (T, generateTopicName(name));
    m_Reader = new Reader (m_Topic, generateReaderName(name));
    m_Writer = new Writer (m_Topic, generateWriterName(name));
  }
};
```

Versus directly:

```
class Talker {
  Topic m_Topic;
  Reader m_Reader;
  Writer m_Writer;


  Talker (Type T, String name) :
    m_Topic(T, name),
    m_Reader(m_Topic, generateReaderName(name)),
    m_Writer(m_Topic, generateWriterName(name))
  {}
};
```

I was talking with a coworker and apparently the latter is bad because of dependency on member initialization order. However, it also has a working automatic copy constructor.

What's the better way to go about something like this, especially if the list of member objects get longer?

Answer (score 5):

A decision like this shouldn't be based on the argument your coworker suggests, since it's an invalid argument. You can control the order of initialization even with object members - see my last paragraph. The decision should be based on:

1) **Functional** - Do you require polymorphic types? Will `Topic`, `Reader` and `Writer` be inherited? If yes, you should use pointers to prevent object slicing.

2) **Logical** Is `Talker` the true owner of the members (objects) or does it just point to some objects that are shared between multiple classes?

#### Old Answer

An alternative is to use smart pointers instead as members. This way you still have the advantages of automatic memory management.

**However**, your coworker's argument is invalid and the latter option is not bad, if you know your C++. The members are initialized in the order in which they are declared in the `class`. So `m_Topic` will be initialized first, `m_Reader` second and lastly `m_Writer`. If initialization order is important (*code smell*), just reorder the members in the class definition.

Comment: I believe the problem exists with maintenance down the line since the definition and body are split into .h and .cpp files in practice. I will look into smart pointers, but I would prefer to stick to the basics.

Comment: @user535474 it makes no difference to maintenance. It's C++. These are the rules. If you don't know them, maintaining anything can be a pain. My suggestion is you tell your coworker you have control over the order, that way he learns something (which is always a good thing), and you don't base your decision on the wrong arguments.

Comment: @user535474 I edited my answer, please take into account the points made as taking the right decision can save you a lot in maintenance work.

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on how you will use these classes, but in general, the fewer heap allocations the better so I tend to frown at the constructor with all those `new`s in it. Is the dependency on member initialization order really a problem? I can hardy imagine why it should be.

If you use pointers, it would be reasonable do it with smart ones, `std::unique_ptr` being the canonical choice.

Comment: You should use automatic storage instead of dynamic. Heap/stack doesn't make sense in terms of members.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your requirements

the pointer version is more flexible

- Objects could be null
- Objects could be exchanged, taken away

but

- you have to take care about correct destroying (ok, smart pointers will help)
- you need more memory at least 3*4 bytes in a 32 Bit memory enviroment, probably more due to implementation details of memory management, very likely double the figures. This hurts when you have lots of small objects

Pointer model is a rather

- car and wheel situation (exchangeable)

Member model is a rather

- house and room situation (could not remove a room without modifying the house)